# How to re-order a table with a certain value at the top

Tags: mysql, alter

For example, I have a table like this:

```
id
|02|
|01|
|03|
|05|
|04|
```

I need to alter the table with 05 at the top:

```
id
|05|
|01|
|02|
|03|
|04|
```

`SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id=05 desc,id` works. But I want to alter the table.

`ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY id` can re-order the table data. But

`ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY id=05 desc,id` does not work.

I have an application which the old version does not order the table, so it displays '02' on top. I cannot update the application any time soon, so I have to re-order the table instead.

Comment: See FIELD(). That's all.

Comment: @Strawberry The table does not have limited number of rows so I can't make a comma delimited list for this function. And it does not work with ALTER

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't find a way to do this without changing the structure of the table. UPDATE works with this kind of ordering, so I have to insert a new column, update it with a variable and alter it

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN id2  INT NULL;
SET @i=1;
UPDATE table1 SET id2=(@i:=@i+1) ORDER BY id=05 desc,id
ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY id2;
```

Comment: If you don't know the answer (and why would you?), you're not obliged to answer.

Comment: What? Don't you know there is "Answer your own question" feature when you ask a question? Everyone have rights to answer their own question or it won't allow me to in the first place. Now remove that downvote

Comment: I have a fair sense of how the site works, thanks. Rows in RDBMS tables have no order, so the actions you describe above are meaningless - and I'll vote as I wish thanks.

Comment: Try using MySQL, create a table with PRIMARY KEY, and insert random numbers. It has order from first record to last one you inserted. What kind of table are you talking about?

Answer (score -1):

`ALTER` table isn't used to manipulate data, it's used to modify table structure. Your best bet would be to `SELECT` into a temp table, `TRUNCATE`, then re-insert from the temp table.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM table1
ORDER BY id=05 desc,id;

TRUNCATE table1;

INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM #temp;

DROP #temp;
```

Comment: BTW, why are you so concerned with the ordering of the tuples?? You shouldn't have to worry about it and instead, just `SELECT` with your `ORDER BY` where ever you are retrieving data out...

Comment: why create a #temp, why not  `truncate + INSERT INTO  table SELECT ORDER` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Was trying to demonstrate the thought process plus I'm not super leet at SQL lol

Comment: @Coderchu As I said there is no way to change how the application retrieve the data.

Comment: ALTER TABLE can permanently re-order the table. I can use `ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY id`

Comment: @Strawberry Rows HAVE  order. Try inserting into one and see for yourself.

Comment: @RedRomanov If you want to think that, who am I to argue? It's almost not worth mentioning that in an RDBMS, a table isn't really a table unless it has a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes it has PRIMARY KEY and it has nothing to do with rows ordering.

Comment: @RedRomanov This is fun, but i can see that further discussion is pointless.